# Postgres sequence's last_value field does not work as expected

Tags: postgresql, sequence, primary-key, auto-increment

I have a table in postgres whose primary key is assinged using a sequence (let's call it 'a_seq'). The sequence is for incrementing the value and inserting the current value as primary key of record being inserted.

Code i use for sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE public.a_seq
    INCREMENT 1
    START 1
    MINVALUE 1
    MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
    CACHE 1;

ALTER SEQUENCE public.AssembleTable_RowId_seq OWNER TO postgres;
```

I am trying to copy a file from a disk and insert the information about copied file to table. There are files with same name in the disk so i'm retrieving the "last_value" from the sequence with this query:

```
SELECT last_value FROM a_seq;
```

and rename file "_" then insert it do database so the file name and the primary key (id) of that file is coherent like:

```
id | fileName                         
1  | 1_asd.txt
```

But when i insert the record, the id is always 1 value greater than the "last_value" a get from the query so table looks like this:

```
id | fileName                         
2  | 1_asd.txt
```

And i've tried to execute the select query above multiple times to check if its increment the value but it doesn't.
Any idea how to get the value which will be assinged to the record before the insertion?

NOTE: I use MATLAB and this is the code is use for insertion:

```
colnames = {'DataType'         , ...
            'FilePath'         , ...
            'FileName'         , ...
            'FileVersion'      , ...
            'CRC32Q'           , ...
            'InsertionDateTime', ...
            'DataSource'       };

data = {FileLine{5}  ,... % DataType
        tempPath     ,... % FilePath
        FileLine{1}  ,... % FileName
        FileLine{2}  ,... % FileVersion
        FileLine{3}  ,... % CRC32Q
        FileLine{4}  ,... % InsertionDateTime
        FileLine{6}  ,... % DataSource};

data_table = cell2table(data, 'VariableNames', colnames);
datainsert(conn , 'CopiedFiles' , colnames , data_table);
```

Comment: show the insert statement please

Comment: To get the next sequence number use the function `nextval('a_seq')`

Comment: I dont see any last_value in your MATLAB code - please post the code in regard to last_value

Comment: @VaoTsun The query `SELECT last_value FROM a_seq;` is being execute before insertion to rename copied file.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name But it increments the sequence value before insertion so there is still 1 value difference between file name and record id.

Comment: What I believe happens for you is: when you select last_value - you get last used sequence value and when you insert row, the default value for id is nextval, which rolls value by one above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**updated**

What I believe happens for you is: when you `select last_value` - you get **last used sequence value** and when you `insert` row, the default value for `id` is `nextval`, which rolls value by one above...

**previous**
I believe you have an extra `nextval` somewhere in middle step. If you do it in one statement, it works as you expect, eg:

```
t=# create table so12(s int default nextval('s'), t text);
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into so12(t) select last_value||'_abc.txt' from s;
INSERT 0 1
t=# select * from so12;
 s |     t
---+-----------
 1 | 1_abc.txt
(1 row)
```

**update2**
as Nick Barnes noticed, further (then initial1) iterations will give wrong results, su you need to use heis proposed `CASE` logic

Comment: The solution i find via your answer was retrieving the last_value increment it in MATLAB and rename file. And after i insert the record both file name and id is same. Thanks!

Comment: @NickBarnes yes - a good point. I did not think to try further iterations. thank you

Answer (score 4):

This is a quirk in the way Postgres implements sequences; as inherently non-transactional objects in a transactional database, they behave a bit strangely.

The first time you call `nextvalue()` on a sequence, it will *not* affect the number you see in `a_seq.last_value`. However, it *will* flip the `a_seq.is_called` flag:

```
test=# create sequence a_seq;
test=# select last_value, is_called from a_seq;
 last_value | is_called
------------+-----------
          1 | f

test=# select nextval('a_seq');
 nextval
---------
       1

test=# select last_value, is_called from a_seq;
 last_value | is_called
------------+-----------
          1 | t
```

So if you need the next value in the sequence, you'd want something like

```
SELECT
  last_value + CASE WHEN is_called THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM a_seq
```

Note that this is horribly broken if two processes are doing this concurrently, as there's no guarantee you'll actually receive this value from your next `nextval()` call. In that case, if you really need the `filename` to match the `id`, you'd need to either generate it with a [trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html), or `UPDATE` it once you know what the `id` is.

But in my experience, it's best to avoid any dependencies between your data and your keys. If all you need is a unique `filename`, I'd just create an independent `filename_seq`.

Comment: "The first time you call nextvalue() within a session [...]" Is it really per session, not per sequence? Running your example multiple times (in different sessions) returns the true last value

Comment: @JGH: Oops, you're right. Think I go this confused with `currval()` (which doesn't work until you've called `nextval()` in your session). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When `INSERT` statement is executed without a value for `id` - Postgres automatically takes it from sequence using `next_val`. List of columns in the variable `colnames` does not have an `id`, so PG takes next value from the sequence. To solve the problem you may add id to `colnames`.

Comment: But the reason i created a sequence is not to deal with the unique id for every file.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid any dependencies between your data and your keys, Please try:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE your_sequence
INCREMENT 1
MINVALUE 1
MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
START 1
CACHE 1;
ALTER TABLE your_sequence
OWNER TO postgres;
```

Answer (score 0):

looking at what you posted, to select the `last_value` of `x_seq` you must call it like a table ie:

```
select last_value from xscheme.x_seq;
```